# Javascript window relocating adding unwanted parameter

Tags: javascript

I've been trying this for a lot of time now. I'm getting a value with the input and I'm trying to redirect the page by adding a new parameter and just passing dummy value 23 for now to the parameter number_range.

However, in the end in the window.location part it adds the parameter myurl/?e=1 always at the start. After that it redirects properly. How do I fix this. Please Help.

Also I'm new to javascript so please forgive my bad code and possible mistakes.

```
<h3>Price Filter</h3>

<input id="number_range" type="text"/><br>
<button onclick="filter_start(this,'gt'); return true;">Greater or equal</button><br>
<button onclick="filter_start(this,'ltt'); return false;">Less or equal</button>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var filter_start = function(el, indicator){

        setGetParameter("number_range", 23);
    }

    function setGetParameter(paramName, paramValue)
{
  var url = window.location.href;
  var hash = location.hash;
  url = url.replace(hash, '');
  if (url.indexOf("?") >= 0)
  {
    var params = url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1).split("&");
    var paramFound = false;
    params.forEach(function(param, index) {
      var p = param.split("=");
      if (p[0] == paramName) {
        params[index] = paramName + "=" + paramValue;
        paramFound = true;
      }
    });
    if (!paramFound) params.push(paramName + "=" + paramValue);
    url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?")+1) + params.join("&");
  }
  else
    url += "?" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;

  window.location.href = url + hash;
}
```

EDIT: Sorry just ran it in another place and this seems to work. I Think the problem then lies in Django's admin template or jquery.

Comment: Oh and I'm using a framework called django and I've used this code in their admin template if it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're missing some curly bracers. I've tidied your code very slightly:

```
var filter_start = function(el, indicator) {
  setGetParameter("number_range", 23);
}

function setGetParameter(paramName, paramValue) {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var hash = location.hash;
  url = url.replace(hash, '');
  if (url.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
    var params = url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1).split("&");
    var paramFound = false;
    params.forEach(function(param, index) {
      var p = param.split("=");
      if (p[0] == paramName) {
        params[index] = paramName + "=" + paramValue;
        paramFound = true;
      }
    });
    if (!paramFound) params.push(paramName + "=" + paramValue);
    url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?") + 1) + params.join("&");
  } else {
    url += "?" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
    window.location.href = url + hash;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but even when I run your code the first time I click the button it redirects me to myurl/?e=1 and only after that the 2nd click it redirects me to myurl/?e=1&number_range=23